# Show div element when all images within it have loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following `div` element and within it I load images. I only want to show the `div#main-slider` when all the images have loaded within it:

I have tried the following jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {  
    $('#main-slider').animate({'opacity':1}, 300);
});
```

But it shows the `div` even when all the images aren't loaded.

### CSS

```
#main-slider,
#main-slider #bo,
#main-slider #bg,
#main-slider #hugo{
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity:0;
    -khtml-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
    <div id="boss" class="tab-container">
        <ul class="slides boss-slides clearfix">
            <li id="1">
                <img src="mobilelp/img/boss_mobile_1.png" />
            </li>
            <li id="2">
                <img src="mobilelp/img/boss_mobile_2.png" />
            </li>
            <li id="3">
                <img src="mobilelp/img/boss_mobile_3.png" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="bo" class="tab-container">
        <ul class="slides bo-slides clearfix">
            <li id="1">
                <img src="mobilelp/img/bo_mobile_1.png" />
            </li>
            <li id="2">
                <img src="mobilelp/img/bo_mobile_2.png" />
            </li>
            <li id="3">
                <img src="mobilelp/img/bo_mobile_3.png" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="bg" class="tab-container">
        <ul class="slides bg-slides clearfix">
            <li id="1">
                <img src="mobilelp/img/bg_mobile_1.png" />
            </li>
            <li id="2">
                <img src="mobilelp/img/bg_mobile_2.png" />
            </li>
            <li id="3">
                <img src="mobilelp/img/bg_mobile_3.png" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="hugo" class="tab-container">
        <ul class="slides hugo-slides clearfix">
            <li id="1">
                <img src="mobilelp/img/hugo_mobile_1.png" />
            </li>
            <li id="2">
                <img src="mobilelp/img/hugo_mobile_2.png" />
            </li>
            <li id="3">
                <img src="mobilelp/img/hugo_mobile_3.png" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="flex-prev">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="flex-next">Next</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this requirement. I found success using the **[imagesLoaded plugin](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/)**.

Pseudo code based on what I currently use in my application:

```
$('#main-slider').imagesLoaded({
    progress: function (isBroken, $allImages, $loadedImages, $brokenImages) {
        console.log('ok: ' + $loadedImages.length + ', bad: ' + $brokenImages.length);
    },
    done: function ($images) {
        $('#main-slider').animate({'opacity':1}, 300);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did the other answers (which required no plugins) not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It can get pretty simple ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gD4Z/)):

```
$(function () {
    var $img = $(".waitFor img"),
        n = $img.length;
    $img.on("load error", function () {
        !--n && $(".waitFor").fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

This effectively waits for all images to either load or error out before fading in the entire container.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple enough problem that I wouldn't want to use a plugin for it. It's actually quite simple, since jQuery provides a convinient .load() function to all image elements:

```
$(function(){
    var loaded = 0;
    var total = 0;
    $(".waitFor img").each(function(i, e){
        total++;
        $(e).load(function(){
            loaded++;

            if(loaded == total)
                console.log("Everything loaded");
        });
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xvau/1/)